# Insert with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I start with this:

```
{"Allowed","20863962"}
```

And would like to insert **label:** and **value:** so it looks like this:

```
{ label: "Allowed", value: "20863962" }
```

I tried with sed, but it does a replace, instead of an insert.

```
echo "{"Allowed","20863962"}" | sed 's/A/label: /' | sed 's/[0-9]/value: /'
```

Output

```
{label: llowed,value: 0863962}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got what you asked for, but that wasn't what you intended.

First off, the output of the `echo` is:

```
{Allowed,20863962}
```

because the shell strips the double quotes out.  To get the correct input to `sed`, use:

```
echo '{"Allowed","20863962"}'
```

Then your `sed` command drops characters, not to mention not handling the double quotes, and being highly specific to your current data.  A more general solution would be:

```
sed 's/{\("[^"]*"\),\("[^"]*"\)}/{ label: \1, value: \2 }/'
```

This looks for two strings inside double quotes within `{` and `}` with a comma separating them and saves the strings (using `\(...\)`) for use as `\1` and `\2`.

```
$ echo '{"Allowed","20863962"}'| sed 's/{\("[^"]*"\),\("[^"]*"\)}/{ label: \1, value: \2 }/'
{ label: "Allowed", value: "20863962" }
$
```

If the general regex is too general, a simpler technique is to use multiple replacements, where you can decide exactly how much importance you attach to the space after the open brace and, more particularly, before the close brace:

```
$ echo '{"Allowed","20863962"}' |
> sed -e 's/{/{ label: /' -e 's/,/, value: /' -e 's/}/ }/'
{ label: "Allowed", value: "20863962" }
$
```

The difference between the two is in the number of substitute operations and their complexity.  In a sense, the single-substitute operation concentrates on the strings and fixes up their surroundings; the multiple-substitute operation concentrates on the surroundings and fixes those up.

---

We could 'rescue' your code using this.  Note that there is no reason to run `sed` twice in this context.

```
sed -e 's/"A/label: &/' -e 's/"[0-9]/value: &/'
```

This finds the double quote and the `A` and replaces it with `label: "A` because the `&` means 'what was matched'.  Similarly with the second replacement.  This does not insert a space after the `{` or before the `}`, but that may be OK.

```
$ echo '{"Allowed","20863962"}' | sed -e 's/"A/label: &/' -e 's/"[0-9]/value: &/'
{label: "Allowed",value: "20863962"}
$
```

Were I using this format, I'd omit the spaces after the colons, but that's me...

Comment: Thanks.  I would like to match any alphabetical character like: `{"authentication_failed","5"}` or `{"denied","2"}`. I tried `sed -e 's/^[A-z]/label: &/' -e 's/"[0-9]/value: &/'` but get error.

Comment: You need to clarify your inputs and outputs. My preferred (first) solution works on both the alternative inputs, producing `{ label: "authentication_failed", value: "5" }` and `{ label: "denied", value: "2" }` (with the spacing matching the stated desired output, but it can be modified to suit). The alternative solution with three `-e` operations produces the same output; again, spacing is fungible. Your original attempt is only barely suited to the original input, and is not something I could recommend, even as amended. You could use: `sed -e 's/"[a-zA-Z]/label: &/' -e 's/"[0-9]/value: &/'`

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '{"Allowed","20863962"}' | sed -e 's/{/{label: /' -e 's/,/, value: /'
```

Comment: Your output doesn't have the double quotes that the question requests.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You're right. I went with the OP's `echo`, not the requested result; easily corrected, but still, that was careless of me.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk -F "," '{sub(/"/, "label: \"", $1); sub(/"/, "value: \"", $2); print}' OFS=","
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{label: "Allowed",value: "20863962"}
```

Comment: Your code accepts the output of the `echo` as given in the question as accurate and then fixes it up, whereas there is a case to be made that the `echo` is a part of the trouble (the string to be echoed should be surrounded by single quotes rather than double quotes, so the interior double quotes are in fact echoed. The output is not 100% space-compatible with the desired output. Also, using `awk` when the question is asking to use `sed` is ... well, another way of looking at it, but probably not as helpful as an answer using `sed`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: All fair points sir. I just assumed that OP is going to run this on an input file rather than on an fauly echo output.

Comment: @anubhava You're right. I need to run it thru an input file. The awk statement works great.